# integrate icoengine into zeppelin crowdsale contract

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

I have the following functions

```
// from https://github.com/eidoo/icoengine/blob/master/contracts/KYCBase.sol
function buyTokens(uint64 buyerId, uint maxAmount, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public payable returns (bool) 

// from https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol
function buyTokens(address _beneficiary) public payable
```

I need to make the `buyTokens` function revert and make it possible only to call the one from KYCBase (see link above).

As per instructions on eidoo/icoengine repository, the `releaseTokensTo` function must be overriden to implement the crowdsale logic.

I am really confuse about integrating the open-zeppelin crowdsale into eidoo icoengine KYCBase model. Anybody can help me?

I tried various ways:

- Making an internal version of `buyTokens`

  ```
  // weiAmount is passed by the caller function as msg.value
  function buyTokensInternal(address _beneficiary, uint256 weiAmount) private
  ```

  after that using it into the KYCBase releaseTokensTo, but I get errors I cannot debug.
- Making the Crowdsale's `buyTokens` revert

  ```
  // kinda like this
  function buyTokens(address _beneficiary) public payable {
      revert();
  }
  ```

In any case I always get the following results from truffle tests

`buyTokens : Expected to be fulfilled but got error: VM Error - revert`

can anybody help me?